# how to pass date variable into form

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

views.py

```
def when(request):
user = request.user
report = Report.objects.get(user=request.user)
reportform = ReportForm(instance=report)

settings = Settings.objects.get(user=request.user)
settingsForm = SettingsForm(instance=settings) 
settings=Settings.objects.get(user=2)
if settings.date_format == '0':
    date=datetime.datetime.strptime('10/31/2012','%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

else:
        date=datetime.datetime.strptime('31/10/2012','%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')  
if request.method == 'POST':            
    reportform = ReportForm(instance=report,data=request.POST)
    if reportform.is_valid():
        report = reportform.save(commit=False) 
        report.user = request.user
        report.save()
        return redirect('/member/media/')

return render_to_response('incident/when.html',{
              'newreport_menu': True, 
              'form': reportform,
               'date':date,


               },
               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

models.py

```
class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    manual_date = models.DateField('Another date', null=True, blank=True)
```

template.html

```
 {{ form.manual_date }}{{ form.manual_date.errors }}{{ date }}
```

The above views rendering the hardcoded date values in template as variable.Instead of hardcode is it possible to show the date from manual_date field in models.And how to pass it in reportform.

Comment: Show complete view code and template as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this, instead of using hardcoded date use `report.manual_date`:

```
if settings.date_format == '0':
    date = report.manual_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
else:
    date = report.manual_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: In views, i am getting the manual date from user and saving in db,so entered date format should change according by the selected format,is it possible to do.This i am just displaying the date variable in template,format is changing.I want it to happen in form,so how to pass date variable in form.

Comment: Any idea how to pass the date variable to reportform.

Comment: Try passing initial data as `ReportForm(initial_data={'manual_date': date}, ....)`.

Comment: throwing this error '__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial_data''

Comment: @user2086641 Sorry, change `initial_data` to `initial`